# MySQL: How to query multiple random rows on a table without unique ids

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sample from a MySQL database since it is too large
Without using

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

since the database itself is pretty huge even for simply iterating through the whole database, what is a way I could randomly sample from the whole table?
Any other tricks I have found on the internet seems to use an auto-incrementing, unique id so I have partially lost hopes on whether there will be a way to do it when there isn't even a unique id, but I was hoping if there were any other ways

Thanks

Comment: If it has an id integer column, you could select 100 of every 3n row (3,6,9 etc), 7n, 13n and union the three sets of rows. Does this work ?

Comment: No... there aren't any integer id's I can use in the table